# SSH prompting for password when there isn't one

Tags: ssh, passwords

I have a small embedded device that runs Linux and an SSH server. This box is set up with one user (root) and no password whatsoever.

Currently, there is one Windows XP-based laptop that is used to run diagnostics on the embedded device. When attempting to SSH into the device from the laptop, the user is prompted for a password, even though there isn't one associated with root. From any other computer, SSH correctly logs in sans password.

On the laptop, this behavior is exhibited when using putty, cygwin, and a virtual machine. Again, on any other computer, this exact same VM will connect via SSH successfully without a password.

EDIT:

It's clear that I don't have a firm grasp on Linux/SSH's ideas of password requirements.

As I said, though, from any other device, ssh root@DEVICEIP will log in without a password once the device's key is stored. It's only this one laptop (and any method of using SSH on this laptop) that is misbehaving.

For reference, here's passwd and shadow:

```
root@ULCB-Linux:/etc cat passwd 
    root:x:0:0:root:/home:/bin/sh
    ftp:x:11:101:ftp user:/home:/bin/false
    www:x:12:102:www user:/home:/bin/false
    sshd:x:13:100:SSH Server:/var/run/sshd:/bin/false
    messagebus:x:103:104:messagebus:/dev/null:/bin/false
    service:x:500:100:Service User:/home:/bin/sh

root@ULCB-Linux:/etc cat shadow
    root:$1$yoD9VQnv$V9iaWdgnoSnp2ASzsgxgI.:15826:0:99999:7:::
    sshd:!:0:0:99999:7:::
    ftp::0:0:99999:7:::
    service::0:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: Are you *sure* the root account actually doesn't have a password? The other computers could be set up with public/private key authentication to bypass manually entering the password.

Comment: having no password is not the same as having a blank password. I'd say check the /etc/password file and make sure it has no password (i think it's just a star in the password field) -- stay logged in while testing obviously in case you bork the file format.

Comment: SSH must always have some kind of authorization. You can however by-pass if you install a certificate witch you can generate with ssh-keygen (Linux) ou puttygen (windows)

Comment: I amended the original with more information. Does this help anyone?

Comment: @Sirex A * in the password field isn't "no password"; it's an old-fashioned way of locking out an account. (No password will encrypt to '*', so having it in the password field results in an account which can't log in no matter what password is given.) I gather there's a newfangled method now as well, but if you see * in the password field, that's what it means.

Comment: fair enough. i just remembered seeing in a book in the last week or so about issues caused by people thinking leaving the field empty meant you couldn't log in at all, rather than there being no password. Must have got confused.

Comment: Please, change the root password on this server!  Hackers can use the /etc/shadow snippet you posted to try to break your root password.

Comment: Neither this computer nor this configuration will ever see the internet. It's supposed to log in without asking for a password anyway, so obviously security in this prototype is not a concern of mine. =)